# Adding a linear gradient /overlay section between two containers to make them seem like one

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I am trying to add a linear gradient/overlay between two containers in order to create the impression that the page has a single background from top to the bottom.
I find this challenging because both containers have to be 100vh, but somehow have to include the green overlay section.

Any advice/hint will be highly appreciated.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: 
Example 1: https://ibb.co/frbLb7
Example 2 : https://ibb.co/czsJw7

Thank you.

```
<body>
    <div class="homepage">
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <!-- End content -->
        <div class="green-overlay">
        </div>
        <!-- End homepage -->
        <div class="second-section">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <!-- end green-overlay -->
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        <!-- End content -->
    </div>
    <!-- End second section-->
</body>

.homepage {
    height: 100% //fallback
    height:100vh;
    background: url("img/homepage.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

.green-overlay {
    height: 25vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(100, 244, 2, 0.1), rgba(100, 244, 2, 1));
}

.second-section {
    height: 100% //fallback
    height:100vh;
    background-color: rgba(100, 244, 2, 1);
}
```

Comment: Those aren't "pages" - just different areas of the same page. I think you want the term "below the fold".

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's more readable now.

Comment: change green-overlay height to 100vh, and use only vh and remove percentage height for all , https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wjdaxw

Comment: I need the green-overlay to start only at the bottom of the .homepage . If I give it 100vh it occupies almost the entire .homepage div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Pseudo-classes [read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

check this code at [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/7o0f9ze4/)

and here's the code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.homepage {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/3872/2592?image=1072");
  background-size: cover;
}

.second-page::after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(100, 244, 2, 0.0), rgba(100, 244, 2, 1));
  margin-top: -135px;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
}

.second-page {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(100, 244, 2, 1);
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div class="homepage">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <!-- End content -->
    <div class="green-overlay">
    </div>
    <!-- End homepage -->
   </div>
   <!-- End second page -->
   <div class="second-page">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <!-- end green-overlay -->
    Lorem ipsum
   </div>
  <!-- End content -->
</body>
```

Comment: you're welcome, and don't forget to mark the answered @spr1x